# Sending a glib signal across threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals, glib

I have a thread created using pthreads that I am receiving progress notification callbacks in that thread. This is done in an external non-glib library. I want the callback to emit a glib signal event, but am not sure how to get the event onto the main (GUI) thread.

The library code looks something like this:

```
struct callback
{
    virtual void onprogress(int progress) = 0;
    virtual ~callback() {}
};

void perform_task_impl(callback *cb)
{
    int progress = 0;
    while (long_task_is_in_progress)
    {
        // perform task
        progress += ...; // how much progress (not %) made
        if (cb) cb->onprogress(progress);
    }
}

void perform_task(callback *cb)
{
    pthread_t threadId;
    pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, perform_task_impl, cb);
}
```

The GTK+/glib code is doing something like this:

```
struct MyObjectPrivate : public callback
{
    MyObject *self;

    void onprogress(int progress)
    {
        // Q: how to send this to the main/GUI thread?
        g_signal_emit(self, signals[PROGRESS], 0, progress);
    }
};

void my_object_perform_task(MyObject *object)
{
    perform_task(object->priv);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emit the signal from an [idle callback](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) which returns `FALSE`.